# opencv undefined reference problem

Tags: opencv, opencv2, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build learning_image_transport from [image_transport tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_transport/Tutorials) on Gumstix Overo which has ros groovy running on [linaro](http://www.linaro.org/).

However, one of dependencies of learning_image_transport -- opencv2 cannot be resolved in system dependency. So I cannot use rosdep to install opencv2.

Then I went to http://opencv.org/downloads.html and downloaded version 2.4.3 and followed [instruction](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation) to install OpenCV.

Then I copy opencv and opencv2 from usr/local/include to /ros_core_ws/install/include so that ROS can find all the header file of OpenCV(such as highgui.h).

However, when I make learning_image_transport, I got the following error:

```
  [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/my_publisher.dir/src/my_publisher.cpp.o
  In file included from /root/ros_core_ws/install/include/opencv2/flann/kmeans_index.h:50:0,
               from /root/ros_core_ws/install/include/opencv2/flann/all_indices.h:38,
               from /root/ros_core_ws/install/include/opencv2/flann/flann_base.hpp:44,
               from /root/ros_core_ws/install/include/opencv2/flann/flann.hpp:50,
               from /root/ros_core_ws/install/include/opencv/cv.h:69,
               from /root/catkin_ws/src/vision_opencv-fuerte-devel/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:41,
               from /root/catkin_ws/src/learning_image_transport/src/my_publisher.cpp:5:
  /root/ros_core_ws/install/include/opencv2/flann/logger.h:73:9: note: the mangling of ‘va_list’ has changed in GCC 4.4
  In file included from /root/catkin_ws/src/learning_image_transport/src/my_publisher.cpp:5:0:
  /root/catkin_ws/src/vision_opencv-fuerte-devel/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h: In static member function ‘static sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> >::Ptr sensor_msgs::CvBridge::cvToImgMsg(const IplImage*, std::string)’:
  /root/catkin_ws/src/vision_opencv-fuerte-devel/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:408:55: warning: ‘static bool sensor_msgs::CvBridge::fromIpltoRosImage(const IplImage*, sensor_msgs::Image&, std::string)’ is deprecated (declared at /root/catkin_ws/src/vision_opencv-fuerte-devel/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:307) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  /root/catkin_ws/src/learning_image_transport/src/my_publisher.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
  /root/catkin_ws/src/learning_image_transport/src/my_publisher.cpp:15:84: warning: ‘static sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> >::Ptr sensor_msgs::CvBridge::cvToImgMsg(const IplImage*, std::string)’ is deprecated (declared at /root/catkin_ws/src/vision_opencv-fuerte-devel/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:405) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  Linking CXX executable ../bin/my_publisher
  CMakeFiles/my_publisher.dir/src/my_publisher.cpp.o: In function `cv::WImageBufferC<unsigned char, 3>::ReleaseImage()':
  /root/ros_core_ws/install/include/opencv2/core/wimage.hpp:399: undefined reference to `cvReleaseImage'
  /root/ros_core_ws/install/include/opencv2/core/wimage.hpp:399: undefined reference to `cvReleaseImage'
  CMakeFiles/my_publisher.dir/src/my_publisher.cpp.o: In function `sensor_msgs::CvBridge::fromIpltoRosImage(_IplImage const*, sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
  /root/catkin_ws/src/vision_opencv-fuerte-devel/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:311: undefined reference to `cvGetMat'
  CMakeFiles/my_publisher.dir/src/my_publisher.cpp.o: In function `main':
  /root/catkin_ws/src/learning_image_transport/src/my_publisher.cpp:14: undefined reference to `cvLoadImage'
```

In wimage.hpp file, it includes opencv2/core/core_c.h which defines:

```
CVAPI(IplImage*)  cvCreateImage( CvSize size, int depth, int channels );
CVAPI(void)  cvReleaseImage( IplImage** image );
CVAPI(void*) cvLoad( const char* filename,
                 CvMemStorage* memstorage CV_DEFAULT(NULL),
                 const char* name CV_DEFAULT(NULL),
                 const char** real_name CV_DEFAULT(NULL) );
```

However, in opencv2/core/types_c.h which is included by opencv2/core/core_c.h, I found:

```
#if (defined WIN32 || defined _WIN32 || defined WINCE) && defined CVAPI_EXPORTS
#  define CV_EXPORTS __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define CV_EXPORTS
#endif

#ifndef CVAPI
#  define CVAPI(rettype) CV_EXTERN_C CV_EXPORTS rettype CV_CDECL
#endif
```

The definition of CVAPI has been comment out. Do I just need to uncomment these lines?

Thanks for any help in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57187/opencv-undefined-reference-problem/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2013-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Quote:

> Then I copy opencv and opencv2 from
> usr/local/include to
> /ros_core_ws/install/include so that
> ROS can find all the header file of
> OpenCV(such as highgui.h).

Do not do that!

Add to your CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
```

and link your targets against OpenCV_LIBS:

```
target_link_libraries( your_target ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4